# Cannot find control with path: 'ingredients -> 0 -> 0'

Tags: angular, formarray

i am trying to build a form for recipes with a nested dynamic input for ingredients. I don't know what I am doing wrong. this is the error of the browser console:

```
Cannot find control with path: 'ingredients -> 0 -> 0'
```

this is my html

```
<div formArrayName="ingredients">
  <div *ngFor="let ingredient of recipeForm.get('ingredients')['controls']; let i=index" [formGroupName]="i">
    <!-- address header, show remove button when more than one address available -->
     <div>
      <span>Zutat {{i + 1}}</span>
      <!-- <span *ngIf="recipeForm.get('ingredients')['controls'].length > 1" (click)="removeIngredient(i)">
      </span> -->
    </div>

    <!-- Angular assigns array index as group name by default 0, 1, 2, ... -->
    <div [formGroupName]="i">
      <!--ingredient-->
      <div [formGroup]="ingredient">
        <div class="form-group col-xs-6">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" formControlName="newIngredient">
        </div>
        <div class="btn btn-success" (onclick)="addIngredient()">neue Zutat</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

and this is my ts-file

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup, FormArray, Validator, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
import { NewRecipe } from '../recipe.interface';
import { validateConfig } from '@angular/router/src/config';





@Component({
  selector: 'app-recipe-creator',
  templateUrl: './recipe-creator.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./recipe-creator.component.css']
})
export class RecipeCreatorComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder) {}
  recipeForm: FormGroup;
  ingredients: FormArray;
  instructions: FormArray;

  ngOnInit() {
    this.recipeForm = this.formBuilder.group({
      name: '',
      category: '',
      prep_time: 0,
      cooking_time: 0,
      price: 0,
      ingredients: this.formBuilder.array([this.createIngredient()]),
      instructions: this.formBuilder.array([this.createInstruction()])
    });
  }
  createIngredient(): FormGroup {
    return this.formBuilder.group({
      newIngredient: ['']
    });
  }
  createInstruction(): FormGroup {
    return this.formBuilder.group({
      newInstruction: ['']
    });
  }
  addIngredient(): void {
    this.ingredients = this.recipeForm.get('ingredient') as FormArray;
    this.ingredients.push(this.createIngredient());
  }
  addInstruction(): void {
    this.instructions = this.recipeForm.get('instruction') as FormArray;
    this.instructions.push(this.createInstruction());
  }
  saveRecipe() {}
  removeIngredient(i) {}
}
```

I'm pretty new to angular and this is driving me insane. The tutorials of the forms around all have code that doesn't seem to be supported by Angular 6. Is there a newer tutorial about nested forms with FormArray anywhere?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm having a similar issue with FormArray, but have not found a solution yet. Have you tried the Angular - Reactive Forms tutorial/demo: https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms

Comment: yes I did, but the nested dynamic form fields are not covered.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar issue in my project. In my case, I had not created a group for each ingredient inside the array. i.e. the array directly contained references to the list of ingredients. 
Why do you assign an array in createIngredient()? This might be causing some confusion. Instead I believe, you should return a new Ingredient object i.e. this.formBuilder.group(new Ingredient('', 0)).

Based on the [reactive-forms](https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms) documentation, my implementation for this project is as follows:

```
export class RecipeEditComponent implements OnInit {
  id: number;
  editMode = false;
  recipeForm: FormGroup;

  constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute, private fb: FormBuilder, private recipeService: RecipeService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.route.params.subscribe((p) => {
      console.log(p['id']);
      if(p['id'] !== undefined){
        this.editMode = true;
        this.id = Number(p['id']);
      }
      console.log('new mode: ' + !this.editMode);
    });

    this.recipeForm = this.fb.group({
      name: '',
      imageUrl: '',
      description: '',
      ingredients: this.fb.array([]),
    });

    if(this.editMode){
      const recipe = this.recipeService.getRecipeById(this.id);
      const ingsTemp = recipe.ingredients.map(ip => this.fb.group(ip));
      const ingredientsFormsArray = this.fb.array(ingsTemp);
      this.recipeForm.setControl('ingredients', ingredientsFormsArray);
      this.recipeForm.patchValue({
        name: recipe.name,
        imageUrl: recipe.imagePath,
        description: recipe.description,
      });
      console.log(ingredientsFormsArray);
      console.log(this.ingredients);
    }
  }

  onSubmit() {
    console.log(this.recipeForm.get('ingredients'));

  }

  get ingredients(){
    return this.recipeForm.get('ingredients') as FormArray;
  }
}
```

and in the template,

```
<div formArrayName="ingredients">
    <div *ngFor="let ingredient of ingredients.controls; let i = index" [formGroupName]="i">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-12">
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-8">
                <div class="form-group">
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" formControlName="name">
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="col-2">
                <div class="form-group">
                  <input type="number" class="form-control" formControlName="amount">
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="col-2">
                <div class="form-group">
                  <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger">X</button>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

In my case, I was missing the following step:

```
const ingsTemp = recipe.ingredients.map(ip => this.fb.group(ip));
```